# How to create simple unlimited depth function parser

Tags: c#, parsing

I plan to create a string command like below

```
string syntax = "Download(TagMatch(Download(\"http://www.aaa.com\"), \"<div title='aa'>\", \"</div>\"))";
MyParser.Execute(syntax);
```

Then MyParser will parse the syntax inside and call the correct method using the parameter with the deepest command first until the outest command. So it basically will

1. Download('http://www.aaa.com')
2. Finish downloading it will list all tag matches  and end
3. It will call Download again but with overload Download(string[] param)

So basically I have these methods

```
private string Download(string download)
{
//return single string
}

private string[] Download(string[] download)
{
//return string array
}

private string[] TagMatch(string webpage, string startTag, string endTag)
{
//return multiple Tag matches the array
}
```

How do I create such parser and call the method in deepest first? Anyone can help me? I am newbie in parsing. I plan to create a library dealing with web scraping only by providing one syntax.

Comment: Before starting to parse the html with a method like `private string[] TagMatch(string webpage, string startTag, string endTag)
`, see [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a decent parser you need to do a few things:

1. Define the language you want to parse properly, using a notation such as EBNF.
2. Use a parser-creation tool based on your EBNF definition of your language.
3. Integrate the generated parser code into your application and adapt your application to use the tree structure that the parser code generates from the input string.

A good tool for creating parsers, including in C#, is the Gold Parser Generator at http://goldparser.org.

But make sure you define your language properly in EBNF first. Don't just hack together a "parser" using regular expressions, they are too limited for proper language parsing.

Comment: `I plan to create a library dealing with web scrapping` Language is HTML

Comment: @L.B The language they want to scrape is HTML, but the commands they want to _enter as text and parse_ to do the scraping is something entirely new. That is what needs to be defined.